# How do I register a new settings page?

Tags: functions, pages, options

I need to be able to create a new settings page, one that will act as a list of information for the user. However, I am unable to find how to do this, can someone point me in the right direction for this? Either to some information or to a question here with the answer.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try a code like this

```
<?php
function theme_settings_init(){
    register_setting( 'theme_settings', 'theme_settings' );
}
```

î This is used to reserve a name for a custom settings array

```
//Add settings to page menu
function add_settings_page() {
add_menu_page( __( 'Contenu éditable' ), __( 'Contenu éditable' ), 'manage_options', 'settings', 'theme_settings_page');
}
```

î This will create the page in the admin

```
//Add Actions
add_action( 'admin_init', 'theme_settings_init' );
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_settings_page' );
```

î Wordpress hooking

```
//Start Setting Page
function theme_settings_page() {?> 
<div>
    <div id="icon-options-general"></div>
    <h2 id="title"><?php _e( 'Contenu éditable' ) //your admin panel title ?></h2>

    <?php if($_GET['settings-updated'] == true): ?> 
     <div id="message" class="updated below-h2"><p>Saved successfully</p></div>
     <?php endif; ?>


    <form method="post" action="options.php">

        <?php settings_fields( 'theme_settings' ); ?>
        <?php $options = get_option( 'theme_settings' );
            $defaults = array(
                'viadeo' => 'http://www.viadeo.com',
                'linkedin' => 'http://www.linkedin.com',
            );
        ?>
        <table>

        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Lien viadeo' ); ?></th>
            <td><input id="theme_settings[viadeo]" type="text" size="40" name="theme_settings[viadeo]" value="<?php (!empty($options['viadeo']))?esc_attr_e( $options['viadeo'] ):esc_attr_e($defaults['viadeo']); ?>" />
            <?php if(empty($options['viadeo'])):?>
                    Please hit the save button in ordrer to save the default values
            <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Lien Linkedin' ); ?></th>
            <td><input id="theme_settings[linkedin]" type="text" size="40" name="theme_settings[linkedin]" value="<?php (!empty($options['linkedin']))?esc_attr_e( $options['linkedin'] ):esc_attr_e($defaults['linkedin']); ?>" />
            <?php if(empty($options['linkedin'])):?>
                    Please hit the save button in ordrer to save the default values
            <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>

        </table>

        <p><input name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Save Changes" type="submit"></p>
    </form>

</div>
<?php
}
```

î This is the code that will display your page

```
//validation
function options_validate( $input ) {
    global $select_options, $radio_options;

    if ( ! isset( $input['option1'] ) )
        $input['option1'] = null;

    $input['option1'] = ( $input['option1'] == 1 ? 1 : 0 );

    $input['sometext'] = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $input['sometext'] );

    if ( ! isset( $input['radioinput'] ) )
        $input['radioinput'] = null;

    if ( ! array_key_exists( $input['radioinput'], $radio_options ) )
        $input['radioinput'] = null;

    $input['sometextarea'] = wp_filter_post_kses( $input['sometextarea'] );

    return $input;
}

?>
```

Finally the code above will save the values of you fields.

You can add this code at the bottom of your functions.php or create a new file (better solution, more readable) and require it in your functions.php

Enjoy

Comment: But where would this be put?

Comment: My bad I forgot to mention that, I edit my answer right away